# change list elements in R

Tags: r, list

I have a list `test_list`:

```
a = c("name1:type", "name2:132", "445", "556")
b = c("name1:type", "name2:132", "125", "-6")
test_list = list(a, b)
```

The original test_list is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "name1:type" "name2:132"  "445"        "556"       

[[2]]
[1] "name1:type" "name2:132"  "125"        "-6"
```

I want to change the `name1` and `name2` in the test_list to "X1", "X2".

My expected output is:

```
[[1]]
[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "445"        "556"       

[[2]]
[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "125"        "-6"
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be:

```
lapply(test_list, function(x) sub("name", "X", x))

[[1]]
[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "445"     "556"    

[[2]]
[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "125"     "-6"
```

Or written as (to avoid anonymous functions):

```
lapply(test_list, sub, pattern = "name", replacement = "X")
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_replace`

```
purrr::map(test_list, stringr::str_replace, c('name1','name2'), c('X1', 'X2'))

#[[1]]
#[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "445"     "556"    

#[[2]]
#[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "125"     "-6"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `rapply`.

```
test_list <- rapply(test_list, gsub, pattern="name", replace="x", how="l")
# [[1]]
# [1] "x1:type" "x2:132"  "445"     "556"    
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "x1:type" "x2:132"  "125"     "-6"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `regmatches/regexpr` with `lapply`

```
lapply(test_list, function(x) {regmatches(x, regexpr("name", x)) <- "X"; x})
#[[1]]
#[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "445"     "556"    

#[[2]]
#[1] "X1:type" "X2:132"  "125"     "-6"
```